# VSCode with Xdebug doesn't stop at breakpoint

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, installation, xampp, xdebug

I have a beginners question. I am fighting to get Xdebug to run for PHP in Visual Studio Code. I tried a lot, but nothing seems to work. VSCode doesn't stop at my breakpoints. Here is a list of things I already have tried or setup:

- I edited the PHP.ini from the Apache server in XAMPP. As you can see I added the dll already:

```ini
[XDebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.idekey="vscode"
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.remote_port = "8066"
zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.3-8.0-vs16-x86_64.dll
```

- Made sure the Apache server listens to the 8066 port.
- In Visual Studio Code I installed PHP debug and other PHP intellisence stuff
- the launch.json in VSCcode is as followed:

```
"name": "Listen for Xdebug",
"type": "php",
"request": "launch",
"port": 8066,
"runtimeExecutable": "C:/xampp/php/php.exe"

"name": "Launch currently open script",
"type": "php",
"request": "launch",
"program": "${file}",
"cwd": "${fileDirname}",
"port": 8066,
"runtimeExecutable": "C:/xampp/php/php.exe"
```

- I also set php.exe as a standard in VSCode:

[image: screenshot vs code php settings]

What am I doing wrong? I bet it is something very stupid. I hope some of you guys have some advice.

Comment: I suggest you find some guide with screenshots and follow it. You may start here: https://learnxdebug.com/

Comment: I will try and read it again. I shall search for version 3. I think I read a lot of different versions without noticing. I am an experienced programmer, but never tried php. It's all kinda new for me. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Looking at your current Xdebug config: 1) you have a mix of Xdebug v2 and v3 params. Convert to v3 params only and clean them up. 2) Xdebug v3 uses `client_port = 9003` by default .. so changing port in VSCode (`"port": 8066` lines) to 9003 may do the job (It has to be the Xdebug port that VSCode listens to -- it's Xdebug that connects to VSCode and NOT other way around: a very common mistake/misunderstanding).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem as followed:

1. I set the Apache server to another port that is not: 9000 or 9003
2. After reading the link i understood that a lot of settings where V2. So i changed the xdebug setting to only:

   ```
   xdebug.remote_autostart = yes
   xdebug.mode = debug
   zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.3-8.0-vs16-x86_64.dll
   ```

https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide

3. in visual studio code I changed the launch.json port to 9003 (which is the default port in Xdebug)

It worked perfectly! Thank you LazyOne!